# Use of \mathbb{} in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I have recently (i.e., yesterday) discovered matplotlib as a much better alternative to Matlab for plots. Unfortunately, my knowledge of python is close to zero.

I would like to use `\mathbb{}` in the legend and/or axes (for example, to denote expected value or variance) and it seems that this requires the additional STIX fonts (see, e.g., [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/stix_fonts_demo.html?highlight=mathbb) and [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/text/mathtext.html?highlight=mathbb)). However, I haven't been able to include these fonts in my code so far.

In the following example, I would like to replace `\mathrm{E} --> \mathbb{E}` and `\mathrm{V} --> \mathbb{V}`. Is there a simple way to do it?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=[3.3, 3.3])
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 8, 'text.usetex': True})

plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], label=r'$\mathrm{E}[x]$')
plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16], label=r'$\mathrm{V}[x]$')

plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')

plt.savefig('filename.pdf', format='pdf')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\mathbb` is provided by the LaTeX package `amsfonts`, so you have to load this package for the figure to compile properly. You can load packages using the `text.latex.preamble` setting, as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=[3.3, 3.3])
plt.rcParams.update({
    'font.size': 8,
    'text.usetex': True,
    'text.latex.preamble': r'\usepackage{amsfonts}'
})

plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], label=r'$\mathbb{E}[x]$')
plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16], label=r'$\mathbb{V}[x]$')

plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')

plt.savefig('filename.pdf', format='pdf')

plt.show()
```

[image: plot with mathbb]

Alternatively, to use the STIX fonts you refer to in your question, you can use matplotlib's built in TeX parser, not using LaTeX at all for your text handling (`test.usetex` can be `False`). In this case, however, note that `\mathbb{}` produces italic text by default, and you need to combine it with `\mathrm{}` as `\mathrm{\mathbb{}}` to get upright text (as in the example you linked). A possible version of your code is then:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=[3.3, 3.3])
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 8})

plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], label=r'$\mathrm{\mathbb{E}}[x]$')
plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16], label=r'$\mathrm{\mathbb{V}}[x]$')

plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')

plt.savefig('filename.pdf', format='pdf')

plt.show()
```

[In this case, this is the result. (posted as a link to limit the height of this answer)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MXHK.png)

Comment: Wow, that was quick! Thanks a lot for your prompt and effective solution!